# When is the maintenance available?

Tags: pixel-people

I was playing Pixel People and I pressed the **Arrival Center** to splice a new clone. Then, I see the word *maintenance* on the bottom. After pressing maintenance, I am greeted by another screen with repair on it. Then, I pressed repair and it told me that all systems were functional. Is there a time where there are faulty systems?

Answer (score 1):

That button is there to help fix bugs with the arrival center.  It's possible to end up in a situation where you can't get new clones, or the clones you have won't let you splice them, or other problems with the arrival center.  It's not a part of the game, per se, just a way to quickly solve a number of weird bugs.